# Dictionary of common web site elements

Tags: client, workflow

To save the co-workers and the clients from confusion a common language to describe the elements of the web site is a good idea I think. I've seen a couple of design pattern sites but I wonder if someone could point me to a dictionary somewhere in the world wide web that describes common elements such as primary navigation, header, footer, utility menus snipplets etc etc.

Comment: I think pattern libraries are a good start. In the end, your organization needs to have their own set of terms since there really aren't universal standards.

Comment: @TonyBolero: If we've answered your question, you can select the best solution so that if anyone comes across the same problem in the future, they know the course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find one that had everything. I found 4 that in combination should cover the majority of web design jargon.

[Web Design Glossary by University of Minnesota Duluth](http://www.d.umn.edu/itss/training/online/webdesign/glossary/)
[Web Design Glossary from About.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignhtmlatoz/a/blglossary.htm)
[The Motive Web Design Glossary](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/index.php)
[Glossary of Graphic Design and Web Page Design Terms by Grantastic Designs](http://www.grantasticdesigns.com/glossary.html) (some terms are illustrated)

Comment: Thanks but even I would be seriously interested IF it is essentially a glossary of design ELEMENTS alone.